# MemoryError in EC2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting this memory error and trying to figure out if this has to do with adding memory to my EC2 instance or if this has to do with the having a larger df. Any help would be great!

Below is the `MemoryError` message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jan_sound_of_ec2_cron.py", line 1592, in <module>
    final_file_path = final_output(playlists_df, track_audio_features_df, albums_df, artists_df)
  File "jan_sound_of_ec2_cron.py", line 1390, in final_output
    merged_df['album_uri'] = 'spotify:album:' + merged_df['album_id']
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 93, in __radd__
    return self._arith_method(other, roperator.radd)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4998, in _arith_method
    result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 189, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 142, in _na_arithmetic_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, left, right)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 235, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 69, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/roperator.py", line 9, in radd
    return right + left
MemoryError
```

Comment: how big is merged_df, and what does it contain?

Comment: @RoryLM It's ~320MB, 472k rows across 37 columns

Comment: You could temporarily change to a larger instance to determine whether that could resolve the error. (Stop the instance, change instance type, start the instance.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein do you know if I would need to set up a new key pair after changing the instance type? I've already changed instance type but now getting a new set of messages when opening up terminal - before even launching EC2.

Comment: The instance is exactly the same, so you would connect using the same keypair. However, the instance will have a different Public IP (unless you assigned a static Elastic IP address). So, make sure that you are connecting to the correct computer. If problems persist, feel free to edit your question to show us the "new set of messages when opening up terminal".